# Python Selenium's Select function does not update web page

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to automate a web page with Selenium in python. In the web page, there is a drop down menu that has 3 options: "Please select" (default), "option 1" and "option 2". I use the following to update its selection from default to "option 1":

```
opts = Select(driver.find_element_by_value("options"))
opts.select_by_visible_text("option 1")
```

The strange thing is that even the drop down menu has not changed, if I call the following code:

```
opts.all_selected_options[0].text
```

It would return "option 1".

So it seems Selenium has already done its job but the web page just does not reflect it. Is that so? How to make sure the web page can also update?

PS: I also tried `select_by_id` and `select_by_visible_text`, the result is the same.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: We need to see relevant HTML structure

Comment: Have you tried to select by xpath?

Comment: does the dropdown uses js?

Comment: Add URL or HTML of the page

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. Eventually I find the root cause of the problem. There is a pop up window that happens to have the same id so Selenium was interacting with that window instead. Thanks again!